# ROS/Moveit ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution

Tags: ros, moveit

I'm trying to run the ur5 arm from *universal robot* package in the Rviz platform.
For this purpose I adjusted the original python code from the Moveit *"Move Group Python Interface"* tutorial:

> http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html

The Error appears every time when I try to run a command that **execute** a movement in the robot arm, as the following image shows:
[Image of the Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SezZm.png)

Here another Image, Left side Rviz Terminal, Right side Python Code Terminal:
[Image of the Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFPTW.png)

Can someone tell me what can I do to fix it or give the reason why is this happening?

For more information, here the modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Software License Agreement (BSD License)
#
# Copyright (c) 2013, SRI International
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
#  * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#  * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
#    copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
#    disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
#    with the distribution.
#  * Neither the name of SRI International nor the names of its
#    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
#    from this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
# INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
# BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
# LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
# CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
# LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
# ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
# POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# Author: Acorn Pooley, Mike Lautman

## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL imports
##
## To use the Python MoveIt interfaces, we will import the `moveit_commander`_ namespace.
## This namespace provides us with a `MoveGroupCommander`_ class, a `PlanningSceneInterface`_ class,
## and a `RobotCommander`_ class. More on these below. We also import `rospy`_ and some messages that we will use:
##

import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
from math import pi
from std_msgs.msg import String
from moveit_commander.conversions import pose_to_list
## END_SUB_TUTORIAL


def all_close(goal, actual, tolerance):
  """
  Convenience method for testing if a list of values are within a tolerance of their counterparts in another list
  @param: goal       A list of floats, a Pose or a PoseStamped
  @param: actual     A list of floats, a Pose or a PoseStamped
  @param: tolerance  A float
  @returns: bool
  """
  all_equal = True
  if type(goal) is list:
    for index in range(len(goal)):
      if abs(actual[index] - goal[index]) > tolerance:
        return False

  elif type(goal) is geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped:
    return all_close(goal.pose, actual.pose, tolerance)

  elif type(goal) is geometry_msgs.msg.Pose:
    return all_close(pose_to_list(goal), pose_to_list(actual), tolerance)

  return True


class MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial(object):
  """MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial"""
  def __init__(self):
    super(MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial, self).__init__()

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL setup
    ##
    ## First initialize `moveit_commander`_ and a `rospy`_ node:
    moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
    rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial', anonymous=True)

    ## Instantiate a `RobotCommander`_ object. Provides information such as the robot's
    ## kinematic model and the robot's current joint states
    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()

    ## Instantiate a `PlanningSceneInterface`_ object.  This provides a remote interface
    ## for getting, setting, and updating the robot's internal understanding of the
    ## surrounding world:
    scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()

    ## Instantiate a `MoveGroupCommander`_ object.  This object is an interface
    ## to a planning group (group of joints).  In this tutorial the group is the primary
    ## arm joints in the Panda robot, so we set the group's name to "panda_arm".
    ## If you are using a different robot, change this value to the name of your robot
    ## arm planning group.
    ## This interface can be used to plan and execute motions:
    group_name = "manipulator"
    move_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)

    ## Create a `DisplayTrajectory`_ ROS publisher which is used to display
    ## trajectories in Rviz:
    display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path',
                                                   moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory,
                                                   queue_size=20)

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL basic_info
    ##
    ## Getting Basic Information
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    # We can get the name of the reference frame for this robot:
    planning_frame = move_group.get_planning_frame()
    print "============ Planning frame: %s" % planning_frame

    # We can also print the name of the end-effector link for this group:
    eef_link = move_group.get_end_effector_link()
    print "============ End effector link: %s" % eef_link

    # We can get a list of all the groups in the robot:
    group_names = robot.get_group_names()
    print "============ Available Planning Groups:", robot.get_group_names()

    # Sometimes for debugging it is useful to print the entire state of the
    # robot:
    print "============ Printing robot state"
    print robot.get_current_state()
    print ""
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # Misc variables
    self.box_name = ''
    self.robot = robot
    self.scene = scene
    self.move_group = move_group
    self.display_trajectory_publisher = display_trajectory_publisher
    self.planning_frame = planning_frame
    self.eef_link = eef_link
    self.group_names = group_names


  def go_to_joint_state(self):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    move_group = self.move_group

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_to_joint_state
    ##
    ## Planning to a Joint Goal
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## The Panda's zero configuration is at a `singularity <https://www.quora.com/Robotics-What-is-meant-by-kinematic-singularity>`_ so the first
    ## thing we want to do is move it to a slightly better configuration.
    # We can get the joint values from the group and adjust some of the values:
    joint_goal = move_group.get_current_joint_values()
    joint_goal[0] = 0
    joint_goal[1] = -pi/4
    joint_goal[2] = 0
    joint_goal[3] = -pi/2
    joint_goal[4] = 0
    joint_goal[5] = pi/3

    # The go command can be called with joint values, poses, or without any
    # parameters if you have already set the pose or joint target for the group
    move_group.go(joint_goal, wait=True)

    # Calling ``stop()`` ensures that there is no residual movement
    move_group.stop()

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # For testing:
    current_joints = move_group.get_current_joint_values()
    return all_close(joint_goal, current_joints, 0.01)


  def go_to_pose_goal(self):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    move_group = self.move_group

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_to_pose
    ##
    ## Planning to a Pose Goal
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## We can plan a motion for this group to a desired pose for the
    ## end-effector:
    pose_goal = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    pose_goal.orientation.w = -1.0
    pose_goal.position.x = 0.0
    pose_goal.position.y = 0.5
    pose_goal.position.z = 0.4

    move_group.set_pose_target(pose_goal)

    ## Now, we call the planner to compute the plan and execute it.
    plan = move_group.go(wait=True)
    # Calling `stop()` ensures that there is no residual movement
    move_group.stop()
    # It is always good to clear your targets after planning with poses.
    # Note: there is no equivalent function for clear_joint_value_targets()
    move_group.clear_pose_targets()

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # For testing:
    # Note that since this section of code will not be included in the tutorials
    # we use the class variable rather than the copied state variable
    current_pose = self.move_group.get_current_pose().pose
    return all_close(pose_goal, current_pose, 0.01)


  def plan_cartesian_path(self, scale=1):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    move_group = self.move_group

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_cartesian_path
    ##
    ## Cartesian Paths
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## You can plan a Cartesian path directly by specifying a list of waypoints
    ## for the end-effector to go through. If executing  interactively in a
    ## Python shell, set scale = 1.0.
    ##
    waypoints = []

    wpose = move_group.get_current_pose().pose
    wpose.position.z -= scale * 0.1  # First move up (z)
    wpose.position.y += scale * 0.2  # and sideways (y)
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

    wpose.position.x += scale * 0.1  # Second move forward/backwards in (x)
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

    wpose.position.y -= scale * 0.1  # Third move sideways (y)
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

    # We want the Cartesian path to be interpolated at a resolution of 1 cm
    # which is why we will specify 0.01 as the eef_step in Cartesian
    # translation.  We will disable the jump threshold by setting it to 0.0,
    # ignoring the check for infeasible jumps in joint space, which is sufficient
    # for this tutorial.
    (plan, fraction) = move_group.compute_cartesian_path(
                                       waypoints,   # waypoints to follow
                                       0.01,        # eef_step
                                       0.0)         # jump_threshold

    # Note: We are just planning, not asking move_group to actually move the robot yet:
    return plan, fraction

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL


  def display_trajectory(self, plan):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    robot = self.robot
    display_trajectory_publisher = self.display_trajectory_publisher

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL display_trajectory
    ##
    ## Displaying a Trajectory
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## You can ask RViz to visualize a plan (aka trajectory) for you. But the
    ## group.plan() method does this automatically so this is not that useful
    ## here (it just displays the same trajectory again):
    ##
    ## A `DisplayTrajectory`_ msg has two primary fields, trajectory_start and trajectory.
    ## We populate the trajectory_start with our current robot state to copy over
    ## any AttachedCollisionObjects and add our plan to the trajectory.
    display_trajectory = moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory()
    display_trajectory.trajectory_start = robot.get_current_state()
    display_trajectory.trajectory.append(plan)
    # Publish
    display_trajectory_publisher.publish(display_trajectory);

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL


  def execute_plan(self, plan):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    move_group = self.move_group

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL execute_plan
    ##
    ## Executing a Plan
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## Use execute if you would like the robot to follow
    ## the plan that has already been computed:
    move_group.execute(plan, wait=True)

    ## **Note:** The robot's current joint state must be within some tolerance of the
    ## first waypoint in the `RobotTrajectory`_ or ``execute()`` will fail
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL


  def wait_for_state_update(self, box_is_known=False, box_is_attached=False, timeout=4):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    box_name = self.box_name
    scene = self.scene

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL wait_for_scene_update
    ##
    ## Ensuring Collision Updates Are Receieved
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## If the Python node dies before publishing a collision object update message, the message
    ## could get lost and the box will not appear. To ensure that the updates are
    ## made, we wait until we see the changes reflected in the
    ## ``get_attached_objects()`` and ``get_known_object_names()`` lists.
    ## For the purpose of this tutorial, we call this function after adding,
    ## removing, attaching or detaching an object in the planning scene. We then wait
    ## until the updates have been made or ``timeout`` seconds have passed
    start = rospy.get_time()
    seconds = rospy.get_time()
    while (seconds - start < timeout) and not rospy.is_shutdown():
      # Test if the box is in attached objects
      attached_objects = scene.get_attached_objects([box_name])
      is_attached = len(attached_objects.keys()) > 0

      # Test if the box is in the scene.
      # Note that attaching the box will remove it from known_objects
      is_known = box_name in scene.get_known_object_names()

      # Test if we are in the expected state
      if (box_is_attached == is_attached) and (box_is_known == is_known):
        return True

      # Sleep so that we give other threads time on the processor
      rospy.sleep(0.1)
      seconds = rospy.get_time()

    # If we exited the while loop without returning then we timed out
    return False
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL


  def add_box(self, timeout=4):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    box_name = self.box_name
    scene = self.scene

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL add_box
    ##
    ## Adding Objects to the Planning Scene
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## First, we will create a box in the planning scene at the location of the left finger:
    box_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped()
    box_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link"
    box_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
    box_pose.pose.position.z = -0.05 # slightly above the end effector
    box_name = "box"
    scene.add_box(box_name, box_pose, size=(2, 2, 0.1))

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL
    # Copy local variables back to class variables. In practice, you should use the class
    # variables directly unless you have a good reason not to.
    self.box_name=box_name
    return self.wait_for_state_update(box_is_known=True, timeout=timeout)


  def attach_box(self, timeout=4):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    box_name = self.box_name
    robot = self.robot
    scene = self.scene
    eef_link = self.eef_link
    group_names = self.group_names

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL attach_object
    ##
    ## Attaching Objects to the Robot
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## Next, we will attach the box to the Panda wrist. Manipulating objects requires the
    ## robot be able to touch them without the planning scene reporting the contact as a
    ## collision. By adding link names to the ``touch_links`` array, we are telling the
    ## planning scene to ignore collisions between those links and the box. For the Panda
    ## robot, we set ``grasping_group = 'hand'``. If you are using a different robot,
    ## you should change this value to the name of your end effector group name.
    grasping_group = 'endeffector'
    touch_links = robot.get_link_names(group=grasping_group)
    scene.attach_box(eef_link, box_name, touch_links=touch_links)
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # We wait for the planning scene to update.
    return self.wait_for_state_update(box_is_attached=True, box_is_known=False, timeout=timeout)


  def detach_box(self, timeout=4):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    box_name = self.box_name
    scene = self.scene
    eef_link = self.eef_link

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL detach_object
    ##
    ## Detaching Objects from the Robot
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## We can also detach and remove the object from the planning scene:
    scene.remove_attached_object(eef_link, name=box_name)
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # We wait for the planning scene to update.
    return self.wait_for_state_update(box_is_known=True, box_is_attached=False, timeout=timeout)


  def remove_box(self, timeout=4):
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    box_name = self.box_name
    scene = self.scene

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL remove_object
    ##
    ## Removing Objects from the Planning Scene
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## We can remove the box from the world.
    scene.remove_world_object(box_name)

    ## **Note:** The object must be detached before we can remove it from the world
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # We wait for the planning scene to update.
    return self.wait_for_state_update(box_is_attached=False, box_is_known=False, timeout=timeout)


def main():
  try:
    print ""
    print "----------------------------------------------------------"
    print "Welcome to the MoveIt MoveGroup Python Interface Tutorial"
    print "----------------------------------------------------------"
    print "Press Ctrl-D to exit at any time"
    print ""
    print "============ Press `Enter` to begin the tutorial by setting up the moveit_commander ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial = MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial()

    #print "============ Press `Enter` to execute a movement using a joint state goal ..."
    #raw_input()
    #tutorial.go_to_joint_state()

    print "============ Press `Enter` to add a box to the planning scene ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.add_box()

    print "============ Press `Enter` to execute a movement using a pose goal ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.go_to_pose_goal()

    print "============ Press `Enter` to plan and display a Cartesian path ..."
    raw_input()
    cartesian_plan, fraction = tutorial.plan_cartesian_path()

    print "============ Press `Enter` to display a saved trajectory (this will replay the Cartesian path)  ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.display_trajectory(cartesian_plan)

    print "============ Press `Enter` to execute a saved path ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.execute_plan(cartesian_plan)

    print "============ Press `Enter` to attach a Box to the Panda robot ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.attach_box()

    print "============ Press `Enter` to plan and execute a path with an attached collision object ..."
    raw_input()
    cartesian_plan, fraction = tutorial.plan_cartesian_path(scale=-1)
    tutorial.execute_plan(cartesian_plan)

    print "============ Press `Enter` to detach the box from the Panda robot ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.detach_box()

    print "============ Press `Enter` to remove the box from the planning scene ..."
    raw_input()
    tutorial.remove_box()

    print "============ Python tutorial demo complete!"
  except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    return
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

## BEGIN_TUTORIAL
## .. _moveit_commander:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_commander/html/namespacemoveit__commander.html
##
## .. _MoveGroupCommander:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html
##
## .. _RobotCommander:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1robot_1_1RobotCommander.html
##
## .. _PlanningSceneInterface:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1planning__scene__interface_1_1PlanningSceneInterface.html
##
## .. _DisplayTrajectory:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/DisplayTrajectory.html
##
## .. _RobotTrajectory:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/RobotTrajectory.html
##
## .. _rospy:
##    http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rospy/html/
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL imports
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL setup
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL basic_info
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_to_joint_state
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_to_pose
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_cartesian_path
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL display_trajectory
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL execute_plan
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL add_box
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL wait_for_scene_update
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL attach_object
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL detach_object
## CALL_SUB_TUTORIAL remove_object
## END_TUTORIAL
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my error and it was basically that since I was working with multiple robots, I had to include my robot(ur5) in the namespace from my robot, which in this case was named /ur5.
The following image of the nodes graph explain the error

[image]

I had 2 move_groups, one outside the namespace(the one not necessary) and the other inside(the only necessary), which had to be only one, the one named /ur5/move_group

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error with same code, but I was only testing cartesian pose goals.

**Issue**:

1. Cartesian solution worked fine with only Rviz (demo.launch)
2. But, not with Gazebo+Rviz
3. Error msg: "`ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution`"

**Possible resolution**:

1. It seems tolerance values were too small for the assigned cartesian pose
2. After changing the cartesian goal pose values, it works fine